# Static variable in JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, static

I am not getting an answer for the mentioned code.
Here `foo.staticVar` is static variable and
`normalVar` is normal variable.
But I am getting the same out for both of them.

```
function foo(){
   foo.staticVar = 0;  // Static variable
   normalVar = 0;      // Normal variable

   console.log('foo.staticVar = ',++foo.staticVar);
   console.log('normalVar =', ++normalVar);  
}   

var a = new foo();
var b = new foo();
var c = new foo();
```

**Output**

**My assumption:**

```
foo.staticVar =  1 
normalVar =      1 
foo.staticVar =  2 
normalVar =      1
foo.staticVar =  3
normalVar =      1
```

**Actual Output:**

```
foo.staticVar =  1
normalVar =      1
foo.staticVar =  1
normalVar =      1
foo.staticVar =  1
normalVar =      1
```

If I am wrong here then can you please modify this example with explanation.

Comment: I have added foo.staticVar.   staticVar is just name.

Comment: you do realise that every time you `new foo` - your code sets `foo.staticVar = 0;`

Comment: How can we make it static

Comment: try moving `foo.staticVar = 0;` outside of `function foo` (after would be a good place)

Comment: So if I put "normalVar" and "Foo.staticVar" outside the 'Foo' function like you said then there is no difference between 2. Both static (Foo.staticVar) and non-static (normalVar) variable behave the same (same output ). And if both behave same then what is the advantage of adding "Foo" which is a function name with 'staticVar' ie...(Foo.staticVar) if it behaves same as "normalVar". I mean that then there is nothing like, a variable is static or not.

Comment: Huh? They don't both behave the same if you move what you call static. See. Your whole previous comment is based on a wrong assumption. Look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new foo`, you're **calling** `foo`, which naturally means that ths line of code within `foo`:

```
foo.staticVar = 0;
```

is executed each time, wiping out any previous value that `foo.staticVar` had and replacing it with `0`.

Instead, to see the difference, move the `foo.staticVar = 0;` *outside* `foo`. Also, you've forgotten to declare `normalVar`, and so your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html); you want to declare it so it's local:

```js
function Foo() {
  var normalVar = 0; // Normal variable

  console.log('Foo.staticVar = ', ++Foo.staticVar);
  console.log('normalVar =', ++normalVar);
}
Foo.staticVar = 0; // Static data member

var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();
var c = new Foo();
```

It's probably worth pointing out that there's nothing special about `staticVar`. It's literally just a property on the function object that `Foo` refers to, like any other object property.

---

Side note: The **overwhelming** convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions (functions you're going to use with `new`) start with a capital letter. So `Foo` rather than `foo`. I've changed it in the live example above.

---

Side note 2: If the [static class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/) proposal moves forward (and it's likely to, it's currently at Stage 3 of [the process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)), you'll be able to do this more "declaratively" using `class` and that proposal's syntax:

```js
class Foo {
  static staticVar = 0; // Static data member
  constructor() {
    let normalVar = 0; // Normal variable

    console.log('Foo.staticVar = ', ++Foo.staticVar);
    console.log('normalVar =', ++normalVar);
  }
}

var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();
var c = new Foo();
```

Comment: So if I put "normalVar" and "Foo.staticVar" outside the 'Foo' function like you already did for "Foo.staticVar"    then there is no difference between 2.  Both static  (Foo.staticVar)  and non-static (normalVar) variable behave the same (same output ).  And if both behave same then what is the advantage of adding "Foo"  which is a function name with 'staticVar'  ie...(Foo.staticVar) if it behaves same as "normalVar".  I mean that then there is nothing like, a variable is static or not.

Comment: The Class example you shared that I got it. Yes we have a static keyword  then obviously it will be static  but I am confused when we don't have static keyword.

Comment: @CodeHelper - It sounds like you may be familiar with `static` as it relates to local variables in C. If so, forget all of that, it's not relevant to JavaScript, which doesn't have that kind of static local variable at all. If you put `normalVar` outside of `Foo`, then (with the code above) it's a global variable, so sure, it's going to have 1, 2, and 3 in it. The advantage to having the property on `Foo` is that it's not global, it's associated with `Foo` rather than freestanding. That has all the advantages of object properties in general, because again, functions are objects.

Comment: Somewhat of my doubt are clear but one is there. So "Foo.staticVar" is not global and "normalVar" is global but I can do anything with both of them since they are outside the function. I mean what are the features that "normalVar"  have but   "Foo.staticVar" do not have because it is not global.

Comment: @CodeHelper - It's more the other way around, `Foo.staticVar` has features a global doesn't have: Better encapsulation, and if you have several functions you need to treat the same, they could all have their own `staticVar` and you could just loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you are initializing that variable in the function that's why every time the function called..variable initializes with 0..if you initialize that variable out of the function then you'll get desired result i.e `
 var  normalVar = 0;
  function foo(){
  foo.staticVar = 0;  // Static variable
  console.log('foo.staticVar = ',++foo.staticVar);
  console.log('normalVar =', ++normalVar);
 }
 var a = foo();
 var b = foo();
 var c = foo();`
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you are calling the function foo the variable which you have declared getting re-initialize, so you will get always both variable as 1.
To get Incremental value you have to declare the variable out side the function scope.